# How do I get a hotel room in the centre when everything is sold out (and more expensive) because of a big event?

Tags: bookings, hotels, amsterdam, booking.com, festivals

I want to visit the Koningsdag (Dutch national holiday) and am looking for a hotel in the centre (not a hostel, I want my own room). I have checked various portals (including Airbnb) and everything at normal prices and in the centre seems to be sold out.

Are there any tricks to get affordable hotel rooms even though there is a big event going on? I only found affordable hotels far away. Is there a way around the big hotel booking platforms?

With a DuckDuckGo search I only found the loyalty programme. But I am not loyal to any hotel chain, I cannot say that I am a very good customer of any Group.

Comment: If you have status with a hotel chain (i.e. you stayed enough nights per year in the last relevant period), some have a "room guarantee", but I think even those policies have exceptions for large events.

Comment: In the centre of _what_?  You tagged your question Amsterdam, but your question title or body do not mention Amsterdam.  Does it have to be Amsterdam, or would you be fine with Enkhuizen, Hoorn, Oosterhout, Wijchen, Nijmegen, Apeldoorn, Harderwijk, Amersfoort, Deventer, Raalte, Rijssen, Hardenberg, Meppel, Winterswijk, or somewhere else in The Netherlands?  Koningsdag is everywhere, but overtourism is only in Amsterdam.

Comment: Unless what you're really Asking is for some secret knowledge, what but either luck or persistence could ever meet your need?

Comment: Why are people staying in hotels for this event??

Comment: @d-b Probably because they are travelling far or want to stay up late?

Comment: There is that famous "plan ahead"; but this cycle some regret for having not.

Comment: I've had this happen twice.  First time was Toronto in the days before the internet; I didn't know they were having the Toronto Film Festival.  I went through every hotel in the phone book, the last one had 1 room left.  Second time was Fargo, couldn't find a hotel within 100 miles.  Discovered that P!nk was giving a concert that night, there were a lot of Manitoba license plates around.  Gave up in that case.

Comment: @gerrit There are no far distances in the Netherlands. The furthest you can get from Amsterdam is about 170 km. Taking a taxi home is cheaper than a hotel room.

Comment: @d-b, part of the fun seems to be to party till you are ready to drop and stay in a hotel for the night. Even if you could almost walk home.

Comment: @d-b Taking a taxi home from Schiedam to Boertange is not cheaper than a hotel room.  Dutch taxis are expensive.  And maybe people don't want to start a 2½-hour taxi ride at 23:00.

Comment: @Sybil We used this "trick" a long time ago, and it may no longer be applicable, so this a comment not an answer, but possibly worth researching. We booked a hotel in Haarlem (a city to the west of Amsterdam), then made use of the frequently running trains between the train station in Haarlem and Amsterdam CS; about twenty minutes for a train ride in either direction as I recall. There would be a bit of walking between the train stations and the respective city centers, but we found it very manageable.

Comment: @gerrit The question was about Amsterdam. Dutch hotel rooms during koningsdag aren't cheap either. And a taxi can take 3-4 people.

Comment: @Willeke Weird.

Answer (score 48):

It sounds like you're not going to find an inexpensive private room in the city center. Hotels don't have any reason to conceal their availability; if you're not seeing things on the normal booking sites, it's because they really are all sold out.

So the next step is to decide which of those criteria is *least* important to you. Which would you least dislike?

- An inexpensive shared room in the city center.
- An expensive private room in the city center.
- An inexpensive private room far from the center.

I find that once I've accepted the "you can't always get what you want" mantra and prioritized my desires, it becomes way easier to make a reasonable decision.

Comment: Not sure that the third category will be available around Koningsdag, unless "far" means "abroad".

Comment: The first category also isn't looking good.

Comment: "Should I just book earlier next year?"

Comment: @gerrit There's plenty of rooms to be found for <100/night in places like Hoorn or Hilversum, which aren't _in_ Amsterdam by any measure but have a fast and frequent train connection. Trains do run normally even on Koningsdag (for values of _normally_ applicable to NS operations these days). Getting much cheaper than 100€ means not going to Amsterdam (looks like one can get to €60 easily in Den Haag, for example).

Comment: @TooTea Question did not mention Amsterdam (except in a tag), but OK!  Didn't expect that central Hoorn or Hilversum or even Den Haag would have OK hotels at €60 at koningsdag.

Answer (score 16):

While the chances of success are low, you can sometimes get impossible-seeming bookings by knowing when the cancellation periods are for people with bookings to cancel without penalty.  If the hotel has a 48 hour window, check then; if the hotel has a one week window, check then.  People with bookings may cancel at the last fee-free minute.

Comment: Or just keep checking the booking site(s) as some people do cancel at earlier times.

Answer (score 11):

You can search on hotels and check their own sites, but I fear you left it too late.

Usually I would advise to go to one of the other Dutch cities but this event is country wide and all cheap hotel rooms in all main and many smaller towns will have sold out.

Your best bet is farther out.
And do check reviews, cheap rooms are sometimes cheap for a reason you will not want to accept.
Hostels would be a good alternative if you could book a private room but those are as likely to be sold out.

Answer (score 9):

When looking for cheap accomodation when I am slightly flexible with regard to the location (that might unfortunately be necessary), I often find it helpful to use booking.com's map view. If you zoom out, you can even cover very large areas, like here, where I am searching for hotel accomodation for one person on April 27th with a price less than 100€:

[image]

In your case, a reasonable alternative to a hotel in the city centre of Amsterdam is perhaps the two available hotels in Amersfoort for 80-85€. They look quite decent, are in the city centre close to the railway station and there is just a 45 minutes train ride from Amersfoort to Amsterdam.

Comment: Or stay in Amersfoort, the party there will be as much fun.

Comment: Much nicer to stay in Amersfoort than in Amsterdam.  Far less tourists there.  Or Apeldoorn, Deventer, Rijssen, Nijmegen, Winterswijk...

Comment: @gerrit *Much nicer to stay in Amersfoort than in Amsterdam*. Judging by the crowds in Amsterdam, my guess is many won't agree ;-)

Comment: @Berend I'm not convinced most international visitors even consider the alternatives.  Having said that, Kinderdijk en Keukenhof also also (at times) suffering overtourism, although probably not on Koningsdag.

Comment: @Willeke Indeed. Or go the other way, to where the real thing is happening (Emmen this year). There's really nothing special about Amsterdam.

Answer (score 5):

I was in a similar situation recently. I decided last minute to go to the ProWein exhibition in Düsseldorf, and of course hotels were either fully booked or very expensive. 200+ euros for a room at Ibis, that kind of thing.

I ended up staying in Frankfurt in a much nicer hotel for half the price, and "commuting" by train. The ICE takes about 1.5 hours, so while not fun, it was manageable.

Maybe try something like this. You won't find a cheap room anyway.

Comment: usually that would work but this is a national holiday with events in all cities, towns and most villages, so you would have to commute across the border to find hotels in city centers.

Comment: Antwerp (Belgium) does have a high-speed rail connection to Amsterdam, though. But same thing: that too is going to be crowded.

Comment: Many years ago I used to regularly stay in Köln for technical fairs in Düsseldorf. Something like 40 minutes commute.

Comment: And on the 40 minute commute read the same book or magazine or catch up your social media at less expense than you would have at the more central expensive place. Or watch the countryside pass by which you might not have had a chance at otherwise.

Comment: @Willeke As shown in Tor-Einar's answer, the entire country isn't booked out, only the "good" places.

Comment: @Willek, yes koningsdag is a national event. But most of the events are aimed at the local population, so I seriously doubt that other cities will have fiully booked hotels too. Amsterdam is really the place that stands out on this day.

Comment: I have heard stories of trying to book in Haarlem, Leiden, Utrecht and a few more and all of the reasonable options booked out. Farther out from the centers of cities is a better option than a central city location. (And not many cheap options in most Dutch cities to start with.) General worldwide solutions do not always work and someone who does not know the local situation is likely to miss that.

Answer (score 0):

- I once slept in an all night cinema. Depends how desperate you are.
- You could also try sleeping a the airport. Maybe not the most comfortable, but if you look like a bona-fide traveller, you are unlikely to be disturbed.
- You could also risk a circular underground train or bus route. Or, get on a night train, and change direction at 2 or 3a.m.
- Or, look for a camping site. You will get your own "room".

Best tip is probably to book now for next year and wait until then.